# Drivers on a laptop for Windows Server

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-server

I would like to set up a "mobile server" which consists of carrying around my laptop. So, I installed Windows Server on it, but some drivers don't work (e.g. touchscreen or network). I've tried researching, since those drivers work on a Home installation of Windows.

The major problem was the network card. When I install the drivers it says something about: "the .inf file contains wrong information about a service". I tried removing all the mentions to x32, but with no success.

What can I do? I've heard you can modify the ISO to include drivers. Would this work?

Comment: the issue isn't that your iso doesn't contain the drivers. The issue is that drivers compatible with Windows Server designed for your hardware DO NOT EXIST. Windows server is not designed to run on notebooks, therefore  it doesn't have drivers for them.

Comment: I get this, but i have the "files" for Windows Home, i tought i could make them work.

Comment: no, you don't get it. Not compatible with Windows Server means "you CAN NOT MAKE THEM WORK on Windows Server".

Comment: What other options i got?

Comment: You don't have options regarding hardware support. Now, what's the purpose of that "server" and why do you think you need "Windows server" for that?

Comment: Other option is to install a "non Server" OS on your laptop. I don't think Windows Professional lacks any feature you need for your "Server"

Comment: I want to run a simple WebSite, and more, while Linux offers me great capabilities, i found out, that i can do it 2x faster with mouseclicks. I know i could just use Apache etc, but i need more, functionaly as a DNS server

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, the problem you've encountered is due to the fact the hardware vendors of your laptop's various components haven't written drivers for Windows Server. There's a cost involved in developing drivers for an OS, so smart manufacturer's don't do this if their target market won't need the drivers.

Normally you can work around this by installing add-on components that you've verified in advance have the required drivers.  Because this is a laptop, that's likely to be difficult.

#### An Alternative: Virtualization

If your laptop supports virtualization, you can use it to run a your desired server OS in a "virtual machine" (VM).

The software that provides machine virtualization is a Hypervisor. The Hypervisor runs on the computer like any other application<sup>*</sup> and therefore has access to the computer's hardware services (e.g. audio or Ethernet connectivity) via the installed hardware-specific driver software.

A "guest" operating system running as a VM doesn't have direct access to the hardware, so device-specific drivers aren't needed.  Instead, the communication between the guest OS and the physical environment's hardware is handled by the virtualization software. All of the drivers required by the guest OS (e.g. for a virtual network card, virtual storage controller, etc.) are provided with the virtualization software and can be installed in the VM's guest OS (if it doesn't already have them as inbox drivers).

**Bottom line:** You can run your OS as a VM without concern for the specific drivers required by the physical hardware.

---

*<sup>*</sup>This is a simplistic view of how a Hypervisor works. I'm leaving out gory details that wouldn't improve the usefulness of this post.*